# Database design for a step by step wizard

Tags: sql, database, database-design, yii

I am designing a system containing logical steps with some actions associated (but the actions are not part of the question, but they are crucial for each step in the list)!

The ting is that I need to create a way to define all the logical steps in an ordered way, so that I can get the list by query, and also make modifications later on!

Anyone with some experience in this kind of database design?

I have been thinking of having a column named wizard_steps (or something similar), and then use priority to make the order, but for some reason i feel that this design at some point will fail (due to items with same priority, adding new items would then have to rearrange the rest of the items, and so forth)!

Another design I have been thinking about is the use of "next item" as a column in the wizard_step column, but I don't feel this is the correct step eighter!

So to summarize; I am trying to make a list (and the design should be open enought to support multiple lists) of elements where the order is crucial!

Any ideas on how the database should look like?

Thanks!

EDIT: I found this yii component I will check out: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simpleworkflow/

Might be a good solution!

Comment: I don't know what language you're using, but have you considered a workflow engine (e.g. Windows WorkFlow Foundation in the .NET world)? It will pretty much do exactly what you've described, but with a nice GUI designer, and features like restartability thrown in for free.

Comment: I am using php and yii-framework and mysql, so I need to to the database design for it!

Answer (score 1):

If I get you well, your main concern is to create a schema that supports ordered lists *and* can provide easy insert/reordering of items.

The following table design:

```
id_list item_priority foreign_itemdef_id
1       1             245
1       2             32
1       3             45
2       1             156
2       2             248
2       3             127
```

coupled to a table with item definition will be easily queried but will be difficult to maintain, especially for insertions

That one:

```
id_list first_item_id
1       45
2       38
```

coupled to the linked list:

```
item_id   next_item  foreign_itemdef_id
45        381        56
381       NULL       59 
38        39         89
39        42         78
42        NULL       45
```

Will be both difficult to query *and* update (you should update the linked list inside a transaction, otherwise your linked list can get corrupted).

I would prefer the first solution for simplicity.

Depending on your update frequency, you may consider using large increments between item_priority to help insertion:

```
id_list item_priority foreign_itemdef_id
1       1000          245
1       2000          32
1       3000          45
2       1000          156
2       2000          248
2       3000          127
1       2500          46    -- late insertion
1       2750          47    -- late insertion
```

---

EDIT:

Here's a query that will hopefully make room for an insertion: it increments priority of all rows above the argument

```
$query_make_room_for_new_item = "UPDATE item_priority_table SET item_priority = item_priority + 1 WHERE item_priority > ". $new_item_position_priority ." AND id_list = ".$id_list;
```

Then insert your item with priority `$new_item_position_priority`

Comment: You are right about my main concern, where I need an ordered list that is easy to add / re arrange and query, and also flexible and *unbreakable*

Comment: @code-zoop I added a sample query that hopefully will allow you to use simpler solution #1. It basically increments priorities of all list items above one threshold to make room for insertion.